# AMPscript, Apex and Visualforce syntax language hinting

Tags: discussion

I've just realized that you can format code blocks on SFSE by adding the following prefix and suffix:

```
<!-- language: lang-or-tag-here -->

insert code here

<!-- end snippet -->
```

Refer to [this page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work) for a complete list of supported language hinting codes.

Refer to [my answer here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/140001/starting-automation-program-using-soap-api/140019#140019) for an example.

This is pretty handy. Note that it's using using Google Code Prettify under the hood. Wondering whether it's worth [submitting a pull request](https://github.com/google/code-prettify#for-which-languages-does-it-work) to add syntax formatting for AMPscript, Apex and Visualforce.

Thoughts?

Comment: I think most of the time you don't need to add the `<!--language-->` comment because it uses the tags to guess the format. Works pretty well most of the time!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that'd make for a very useful feature! I'm sure some existing resources can be leveraged using the definition files for the various IDEs that are knocking about the place.

Comment: Agreed. Once you you build/borrow the regex patterns, it should be straightforward to do. I plan to do one for AMPscript.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a few for AMPscript before, it's been a long time since I've been doing dev so I can't say which one is truly the best.

A colleague of mine is using [this](https://bitbucket.org/psapir/ampscript-extensions/wiki/Home) currently and said it was ok.